# anyone with a criminal record

Tags: negation, quantifiers

a. Anyone with a criminal record cannot apply for this job.

b. Anybody who is Tom's friend cannot be trusted.

Are the above sentences grammatical and meaningful?

I tend to use 'nobody who... can...' in these situations, but I think (a) and (b) are correct as well. Just had a nagging doubt.

Answer (score 2):

I would make a couple of changes to your first example:

1. Use **should** instead of **can**.

There's nothing to stop a person with a criminal record from applying for the job, so that person *can* apply for the job, but *shouldn't* because they will be automatically disqualified.

2. Use **someone/somebody** instead of **anyone/anybody**.

This is debatable, but since the unspecified person has a criminal record, it's more specific than just anybody. So:

> Someone with a criminal record should not apply for this job.

Your second example is fine. I personally would say "Anyone," but you could use anybody, anyone, somebody or someone.